Fluent Bit Logs Not Appearing for New Windows Core Nodes in EKS
We are using Fluent Bit in our EKS cluster with custom Windows Core nodes. When a new Windows node is created, the logs from the pods running on it and the node itself do not appear in our CloudWatch log groups. However, if we manually restart the node, the logs start appearing in the log groups as expected.
We have checked the Fluent Bit pod logs and found no errors. We are looking for possible reasons why this might be happening and need help to resolve the issue to avoid manual restarts in the future.
Can you provide guidance on what could be causing this issue and how to troubleshoot or fix it?
Thank you.
